# IdentityServer4 and Clients Running on iOS 9.3.5 (JavaScript disabled)

Tags: ios, oauth, safari, identityserver4, openid-connect

Let me just preface this by saying that I am very new to web development and OpenIdConnect/OAuth, I have tried everything I can think of to track down the problem without success, so now I'm turning to the community...

I setup an Identity Provider using IdentityServer4 - Nuget Pkg 2.1.1

I setup an MVC client web application using the IDP to authenticate using a Hybrid flow and everything works fine on multiple devices and browsers, except for iPads running iOS 9.3.5

On these devices (replicated on 3 different iPads running the same iOS version), the authentication process starts; the user is asked to login to the IDP and then the browser (Safari) just sits at a blank screen at the authorize endpoint.

Looking at the logs for the IDP, I can see the request "is" being processed and the Authorization Endpoint Response does appear to be generated - there is no obvious sign of an issue.

I have tried setting up test client web applications using examples provided with IdentityServer4 including using the "Implicit" flow and the results are the same.

At this point, I feel it must be an issue with iOS 9.3.5 (at it does seem that version of the OS has a LOT of issues) but I have been unable to find anything to explain this particular issue.

I am hoping someone out there has had a similar experience and can confirm this is a bug in iOS and perhaps offer some kind of workaround.

**Update:**
The problem appears to be an issue with Safari blocking JavaScript in the authorization response that posts to the client callback URL.
If we turn off JavaScript in Safari, then we see the "Click To Continue" button at this step and can continue to complete the authentication and proceed into the application.  Obviously this isn't a workable solution.  My question is whether there is a way to augment the process (presumably through the IdentityServer4 middleware configuration) to prevent the JavaScript from being disabled?

**Update:**
We narrowed this down further to an issue with Content Security Policies.
When the response is generated by IdentityServer4 it includes a CSP of:

> default-src 'none'; script-src 'sha256-VuNUSJ59bpCpw62HM2JG/hCyGiqoPN3NqGvNXQPU+rY='

Older browsers that understand CSP, but not the newer inline script hashing resorted to 'none' blocking the script.

It also turns out that IdentityServer4 released an update (2.2.0) just 4 days ago (been grinding on this for 8 days) which addresses this problem by adding feature #2035 which allows for the configuration of a CSP level to support; setting this new option to CSP1 allows older browsers to process the inline scripts.

[IdentityServer4 Feature #2035](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/pull/2035)

Comment: I can't confirm anything for this version, but we've used newer versions of iOS and IDS4 and we haven't seen such a problem. Btw - isn't this version way too old?

Comment: Yes, we have had users on newer (and some older) iOS devices and they work just fine.  The issue seems to be limited to iOS9.  iOS9 was released Sept. 2015, so old, but I guess I wouldn't say way too old for someone wanting to use a web application. Maybe just too old for this technology.

Comment: Wait, are you saying that you have iOS8 users, and it works for them? But honestly for me, this has nothing to do with the OS itself. Do you have another browser on the mentioned device. Why don't you try with Chrome or FireFox and see if it still crashes.

Comment: It has worked on an old iTouch - I think that's iOS 5 or 6 (don't have it to hand) and have confirmed it works on devices running iOS 10+  We have had users try alternate browsers, like Chrome and FireFox which still doesn't work - though it's my understanding these are really just facades on top of Safari and not really full-blown browser apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IdentityServer4 just recently released an update (2.2.0) which adds [Feature #2035](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/pull/2035) allowing for the configuration of a CSP level to support.

Setting the new *options.Csp.Level* option to 1 allows older browsers to process the inline scripts.